# Insert into table1 (select columns from table2) using ibatis, not recognizing parameter value

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I am using an insert into select mysql query, but in the select statement I am passing a parameter(map) from Java. This query is written using iBatis framework. The query is not recognizing the passed value in the select statement.

I have tried changing `#id#` to 
 `#{id}`, `$id$`, `#{id}` and `${id}` but didn't succeed.

The query goes like this:

```
    <insert id="someId" parameterClass="map" >
    insert into table1(id, column1, column2)
    (
      select #id#, A.column1, A.column2
            from table2 A left outer join table3 B on A.column = B.column
                 where <condition>
                      order by column1, column2
    )
    </insert>
```

I have sent the request parameter as a 13-digit long id.
In the table1 schema, id has bigint(20) as its datatype.

I want whatever parameter(id) I am passing to the query to be inserted in the table.

Now the problem is that it is not recognizing the value of `#id#`.
As the id column constraint is not null, it is throwing `"MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null" after running the above statement.`

What should I try instead of #id# to get it working? Or could it be some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

In MyBatis, a `#{param}` parameter is a "safe" parameter than can only replace scalar values. For safety it cannot be used to add any free content to your SQL statement so you can forget about SQL Injection issues. Even if you try the nastier parameter values you can think of, you'll still be safe and you'll sleep well at night.

Now, if you want to insert any arbitrary content to your SQL (to produce some kind of dynamic SQL) **and risk sleepless nights** MyBatis offers you `${param}` parameters (did you spot the difference?). These string parameters are directly inserted into your SQL statement. With this strategy your query should look like:

```
<insert id="someId" parameterClass="map" >
insert into table1(id, column1, column2)
(
  select ${id}, A.column1, A.column2
        from table2 A left outer join table3 B on A.column = B.column
             where <condition>
                  order by column1, column2
)
</insert>
```

Now, please note this strategy is vulnerable to SQL Injection when not managed appropriately. Make sure the value for the `id` parameter comes from inside your app **and NEVER retrieved from the web page or other external user interface or app**.